# c# swf banner is not displyed

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, swfobject

I download swf banner

```
var data = new HTTPProxy().GetBytes(swfUrl);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data, 0, data.Length);
litSwf.Text = "data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64," + base64String;
```

and display on my page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phHead" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#banner').flash({
        swf: '<asp:Literal ID="litSwf" runat="server" />',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        wmode: 'transparent'
    });
});
</script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and html looks like this:

```
<object data="data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64,Q1dTC(...)N/XRmG"     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_397386681" width="100%"   height="100%">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="data:application/x-shockwave- flash;base64,Q1dTC(...)/XRmG">
</object>
```

but the banner is not displayed. If I put url directly:

```
litSwf.Text = swfUrl;
```

then works fine. 
This is part of bigger solution where I have to store swf files in database and display them based on custom logic. So I cannot rely on url. 
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost a decode since I've done ASP web forms stuff, but judging from the parameter name `Text`, it's probably safe to say that component is expecting a **path** to a swf file.

So it would seem, that you are trying to shove base64 binary data into a component that is expecting a path.

What you need to do, is create a separate ASP page/handler, that dishes out the binary data. Then use that page as the path.

Your ASP page could look something like this (this is just off the top of my head, not tested or necessarily exact code):

```
//pass the swf url in as a querystring parameter

//get your bytes from your database
var data = new HTTPProxy().GetBytes(swfUrl);

//set the content type:
Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash"; //not sure if this is right or not
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```

Then in your other page:

```
litSwf.Text = "mySwfHandler.aspx?swfUrl=" + swfUrl;
```